# Given a sequence of values in a 2D numpy array, how to determine the locations of the smallest values in the sequence?

Tags: python, numpy, boolean

I have 2 Numpy 2D arrays, both with the same shape. One of the arrays is boolean, the other is an array of numbers. For example, I may have arrays of the following form:

```
import numpy as np
bool_array = np.array([[False,False,False,False,False],[False,False,True,True,True],[False,True,True,False,False]])
num_array = np.array([[2.5,3.4,9,1.2,7.5],[9.01,4.6,2,4,1],[7.3,4.5,6.3,10,2]])
```

In any row of bool_array where there are one or more True values next to each other, I want to get the corresponding values in num_array and determine the location of the minimum of these values. In the example I gave, there are a string of True values in row 2, columns 3, 4, and 5 in bool_array and another string in row 3, columns 2 and 3. The corresponding values in num_array in each row are 2, 4, and 1 in row 2 and 4.5 and 6.3 in row 3. The minimum in row 2 is 1, and its location in the array is row 2, column 5. The minimum in row 3 is 4.5, and its location in the array is row 3, column 2. I want to get both of these locations.

What is the most efficient way to do this?

Comment: [`min(num_array[bool_array])`](https://uscript.co/public/Google_108617488638529745626/python/f4ba2b45.py)

Answer (score 0):

This should be fast, but I don't know for certain if it is the most efficient way possible. Generally you try to avoid using loops when dealing with numpy arrays and rather try to use numpy ufuncs that are designed specifically to perform the loops internally in machine code that is significantly faster than interpreted python.

```
import numpy as np
bool_array = np.array([[False,False,False,False,False],[False,False,True,True,True]])
num_array = np.array([[2.5,3.4,9,1.2,7.5],[9.01,4.6,2,4,1]])

minimum = num_array[bool_array].min()
index = np.argwhere((num_array == minimum) & bool_array)
```

Comment: I realize that I made a mistake when I posted my question. I've edited the question. For example, if there are sequences of True values in 2 rows, I want the locations of the minimums in both rows. Can you help me with this? Thank you for your help so far.

Comment: Let's say in one row you have `[True,True,False,True,True]` and `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`. Would you want for both sequences of `True` in that same row to calculate an individual minimum, so 2 and 4, or a global minimum for the row for all elements where the bool_array in that row is `True`, so just 1?

Comment: I want for both sequences of True in that same row to calculate an individual minimum, so I want the locations of both 2 and 4.

Comment: Ok, honestly I don't know how to do that using numpy ufuncs right of the bat. I could come up with a solution using for loops but that is way more inefficient than using ufuncs. If you are dealing with very large arrays, this might slow down the code quite significantly, if that's a problem for you.